connect to admin panel PGBOUNCER from odbc
For monitoring from zabbix via ODBC (I don’t want to install an agent on the server). I want to connect to the pgbouncer admin panel from ODBC. I can easily connect to any database except the special one - pgbouncer (which is the admin panel). I've tried adding different options to the ignore_startup_parameters parameter. But there is no success yet.
isql TEST_pgbouncer -v
[08P01][unixODBC]ERROR: invalid command 'SET DateStyle = 'ISO';SET extra_float_digits = 2;show transaction_isolation', use SHOW HELP;
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect

config file for pgbouncer
[databases]
postgres = host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=postgres
* = host=127.0.0.1 port=5432

[pgbouncer]
logfile = /var/log/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.log
pidfile = /home/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.pid
listen_addr = 0.0.0.0
listen_port = 6432
unix_socket_dir = /var/run/postgresql
auth_type = scram-sha-256
auth_file = /etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt
auth_query = SELECT usename, passwd FROM pg_shadow WHERE usename=$1
auth_user = postgres
admin_users = postgres
stats_users = postgres
ignore_startup_parameters = extra_float_digits,geqo,search_path,"show transaction_isolation"

pool_mode = session
server_reset_query = DISCARD ALL
max_client_conn = 10000
default_pool_size = 20
query_wait_timeout = 120
reserve_pool_size = 1
reserve_pool_timeout = 1
max_db_connections = 1000
pkt_buf = 8192
listen_backlog = 4096

log_connections = 0
log_disconnections = 0
#disable_pqexec = 1
verbose = 2
unix_socket_dir = /tmp

